# Assignment operator C++

Tags: c++, calendar, assignment-operator

I'm trying to implement an assignment operator but I keep getting some errors:

```
calendar.cpp:25: error: prototype for ‘lab2::Calendar<T>& lab2::Calendar<T>::operator=(lab2::Calendar<K>)’ does not match any in class ‘lab2::Calendar<T>’
calendar.h:19: error: candidate is: template<class T> template<class K> lab2::Calendar& lab2::Calendar::operator=(lab2::Calendar<K>)
make: *** [calendar.o] Error 1
```

I've also encountered `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&'`, when trying different solutions.

The calendar has date type T, i.e. the dates within the calendar can be other than gregorian. But I also want to be able to assign to a calendar from a calendar with another date type.

Here is my declaration and implementation.

```
//calendar.h
template <typename T>
class calendar {
//...
template <typename K> Calendar& operator=(const Calendar<K> c_other);
//...
}

//calendar.cpp
//...
template <typename T, typename K>
Calendar<T>& Calendar<T>::operator=(const Calendar<K> c_other) {};
//...
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You cannot separate the template definition into a cpp file - leave it in the header file.

Comment: But we already have similar definitions which works fine, for example the constructor:

In Calendar.h:
    Calendar();

In Calendar.cpp:
    template <typename T>

    Calendar<T>::Calendar() {  

            date = new T;

    };

Our problem is the "K". We don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's some problem with your use of templates.
For first you want to use reference passing, instead of value. That way, you are in control to create the parameter object.

```
template <typename K> Calendar& operator=(const Calendar<K>& c_other);
```

Then, the real problem comes:

```
template <typename T, typename K>
Calendar<T>& Calendar<T>::operator=(const Calendar<K>& c_other) {};
```

This is in the source file so the rest of the code won't find the specialisation. You should move the implementation of the method in to the header file, that way, all the calling sites can substitute their own template parameters and specialize the class and the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Move body(implementation) of your `operator=` to *.h* file.

> Because templates are compiled when required, this forces a
>   restriction for multi-file projects: the implementation (definition)
>   of a template class or function must be in the **same** file as its
>   declaration. That means that we cannot separate the interface in a
>   separate header file, and that we must include both interface and
>   implementation in any file that uses the templates.

More information is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

**UPDATE:** If sometimes some declarations works when they declared in a source file, be sure the all objects of that class are in <strike>same source file</strike> same translation unit.

Comment: How come all of the other template member functions work, all though I have them in the .cpp?

Comment: They only work within the the source file. The compiler won't know how to deal with them during the compilation of an other source file.

Comment: As @progician said, it will work only in the source file where constructor is defined.

Comment: The restriction isn't that the declaration and definition must appear in the same *file*.  It is that they must appear in the same translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others said, the correct syntax for a definition of a member function template of a class template is:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename K>
Calendar<T>& Calendar<T>::operator=(const Calendar<K>& c_other)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
class Calendar
{
public:
    T i;
    Calendar(const T & i_in):i(i_in){}
    template <class T2>
    Calendar <T>& operator=(const Calendar<T2> &);
};

template <class T>
 template <class T2>
Calendar<T>& Calendar<T>::operator=(const Calendar<T2>& t2)
{
 if (this == (void*) &t2) //avoid self assignment
  return *this; 

 this->i = t2.i; //implicit conversion here for example double to int or vice versa
 return *this;  
}
```

Condider this code. I call this an asymmetrical assignment operator since the template arguments are different. If an implicit conversion does not exist you will have to do the conversion work yourself. You can try it with this code :

```
int main() {
    Calendar<double> tmp(2.0);
    std::cout << "Tmp i : " << tmp.i << std::endl;
    Calendar<int> tmp_2(1);
    std::cout << "tmp_2 i : " << tmp_2.i << std::endl;
    tmp = tmp_2;
    std::cout << "Tmp i : " << tmp.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```